# Dynamically set child View $el and have Backbone events fire

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I have a parent view (and associated model), with several children Views with the same associated model.  The parent view is defined statically from the HTML.   These events are working fine.

The children views are created dynamically, and are ultimately different, but have some similar initial structure.  The #id s will be different from each other (using the view id number) so that we can know which one is interacted with by the user.  I have tried the following from reading around:

- Adding the `el` declaration when I create the View (towards the end of the JS)
- statically defining it, then trying to update it.
- using `_.ensureElement()`
- setting the el in the `init()`

But I just can't seem to get it for the children views on a fiddle.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chrisfrisina/Xx34G/)

JS: Parent

```
  //The view for our measure
  parentModule.View = Backbone.View.extend({
    //
    //This one is static, so I can set it directly, no problem, the events are working
    //
    el: $('#measure-container'),
    events: {
        'click .test': 'test'
    },
    test: function(){
      alert('test');
    },
    initialize: function() {
      this.template = _.template($('#instrument-template').html());
    },
    render: function(){
      $(this.el).append(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
      return this;
    }
  });

  return parentModule;
});
```

JS: Child

```
  // THe child views are dynamic, so how do I set their id's dynamicall and still get the click events to fire?
  //
  childModule.View = Backbone.View.extend({
    //
    // Do I set the el here statically then override?
    //
    events: {
      'click .remove-rep' : 'removeRepresentation',
      'click .toggle-rep' : 'toggleRepType',
      'click .sAlert': 'showAlert'
    },
    initialize: function(options) {
      //
      //Do I set the el here using ensure_element?
      //
      this.model=options.model;
    },
    render: function(){
      //
      // Do I Set it here when it renders?
      //

      this.template = _.template($('#rep-template').html());
      $('#measure-rep-container').append(this.template());
      return this;
    },
    showAlert: function() {
      alert("This is an alert!");
    }
  });
```

JS: Instantiation

```
define( "app", ["jquery", "backbone", "parentModule", "childModule"], function($, Backbone, ParentModule, ChildModule) {    
  var app = {};
    app.model = new ParentModule.Model({ name: "Snare", numOfBeats: 4 });
    app.view = new ParentModule.View({ model: app.model });
    app.view.render();

    app.firstRepChildModel = new ChildModule.Model({ id: 1, type: 'circle', parentModel: app.model });
    // 
    // Do I add the el as a parameter when creating the view?
    // 
    app.firstRepChildView = new ChildModule.View({ el:'#rep'+app.firstRepChildModel.get('id'), model: app.firstRepChildModel });
    app.firstRepChildView.render();

    app.secondRepChildModel = new ChildModule.Model({ id: 2, type: 'line', parentModel: app.model });
    // 
    // Do I add the el as a parameter when creating the view?
    // 
    app.secondRepChildView = new ChildModule.View({ el:'#rep'+app.secondRepChildModel.id, model: app.secondRepChildModel });
    app.secondRepChildView.render();
  return app;
});
```

HTML:

```
<h3>Measure View</h3>
    <div id="measure-container">
    </div>

<!-- Templates -->
<script type="text/template" id="instrument-template">
  <div class="instrument">
      I am an instrument. My name is <%=name%>. <br/>
      Here are my children repViews: <br/>
      <div id="measure-rep-container">
        <div class="btn btn-primary test">Add a rep</div>
      </div>
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="rep-template">
  <div class="rep" id="rep<%=this.model.id%>">
      I am a repView <br/>
      My ID is 'rep<%=this.model.id%>' <br/>
      My el is '<%=this.$el.selector%>'<br/>
      My type is '<%=this.model.type%>' <br/>
      I have this many beats '<%=this.model.numOfBeats%>' <br/>
      <div class="beatContainer"></div>
      <div class="btn btn-danger remove-rep" id="">Remove this rep</div>
      <div class="btn btn-primary toggle-rep" id="">Toggle rep type</div>
      <div class="btn sAlert">Show Alert</div>
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: try to isolate the problematic code

Comment: @Blaine It is as much as can be in a requireJs environment.  See the comments for where the issues are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every view has a associated `el`, whether you set it directly or not, if you don't set it then it's `el` is just a empty div.

In your code you aren't modifying your child view's `el` or attaching it to the `DOM`.

Try the following

```
render: function(){

  this.template = _.template($('#rep-template').html());
  //this sets the content of the el, however it still isn't attached to the DOM
  this.$el.html(this.template()); 
  $('#measure-rep-container').append(this.el);
  return this;
},
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chrisfrisina/Xx34G/)

As a separate point if you are going to be reusing the same template multiple times you might want to just compile it once, for example

```
childModule.View = Backbone.View.extend({

events: {
  'click .remove-rep' : 'removeRepresentation',
  'click .toggle-rep' : 'toggleRepType',
  'click .sAlert': 'showAlert'
},

//get's called once regardless of how many child views you have
template: _.template($('#rep-template').html()), 

render: function(){
  this.$el.html(this.template()); 
  $('#measure-rep-container').append(this.el);
  return this;
},
```

Comment: these views aren't dynamic though.  You are only calling `#rep-template`, not something like `#rep-template-dynamicNumber1` or `#rep-template-dynamicNumber32`, hence why I am attaching the unique identifier to the DOM ID

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but If you pass in a `el` then that element must exist on the page at that point, if you want a unique id you can always assign the id from within your view. I've updated the fiddle to illustrate.

Comment: Further what you probably want is for your parent view to create the child view's and attach them, something like the following http://jsfiddle.net/KqrF9/74/

Comment: So you are using the shortcut `$el` to get the jquery element, (which when instantiated, was just the empty div), then setting the `id` on it.  you then compile the template and put the compiled template into the child view, and append it where it says to.  I think I was trying to put the `id` in the compiled template, so i think that was the problem, right?

Comment: Never heard of a template key, so if I want to use it, does it have to have all the same values in the compiled template, or can they be different, as long as the structure of the HTML template is the same?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *key*, but if you mean [compiled](http://underscorejs.org/#template) then yes you can just pass in the values you want and *interpenetrate* them.

Comment: Regarding setting the *id* of the `el`, you might also want to specify the class in your view (you can use the [className](http://backbonejs.org/#View) property for that) and then get rid of the outer div in your template since it is probably extra (inspect the resulting HTML and you should see what I mean).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56226/discussion-between-chris-frisina-and-jack).

Comment: @pmain8 Not sure why the link broke, but I'll try and recreate it a bit later today.

Comment: @pmain8 I just took a look again and the fiddle i linked to was an update to the fiddle the [chris Frisina](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1234721/chris-frisina) (the OP) posted. Since that one is down (maybe they deleted it) the one I based off of it is also down. Unfortunately there was some additional code that was only in the fiddle (such as the models etc). I've recreated it but It might be missing some parts.

Comment: @Jack Not sure why the fiddle  broke, but to my knowledge this is the original code : http://jsfiddle.net/chrisfrisina/Xx34G/ . updated link in question as well.   Sorry for any inconvenience...

Comment: @chrisFrisina Thanks, but that fiddle looks like the working version of your code (not sure if those are my modification or what you did after I posted my answer). I'll update my post to link to that fiddle (technically the one in your post is now incorrect but I fiddles are anyway only supposed to support the question or answer for precisely this reason).